# cant install rails in windows when behing a proxy

Tags: windows, ruby-on-rails

I am trying to experiment with rails on windows at work. At work we sit behind a proxy I think that is why following command is not working.

How can I set HTTP proxy environments from windows command line?

```
C:\>gem install rails
ERROR:  http://gems.rubyforge.org/ does not appear to be a repository
ERROR:  could not find gem rails locally or in a repository
```

Answer (score 0):

[Either use](http://docs.rubygems.org/read/chapter/13#page51) the `set` command to set the `HTTP_PROXY` environment variable, or use the `--http-proxy` argument to `gem`.

Comment: Could you also please tell us how can we do the same in the Ubuntu terminal?. I am using Ubuntu 10.04. Thanks...!

Comment: ​With `export`.